# How to get the values on check and uncheck using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a list of items, taken from API and displayed in HTML.
But the list is disabled, i am not able to check and Uncheck the values.

My Requirement:

```
1. I want `HasHomeDashboard`to be disabled and it must be active always.
2. I must be able to check and uncheck the checkboxes except `HasHomeDashboard`.
3. On click of `save Changes`, i want to get in console in this format
```

TS:

```
saveSidebar() {
     let params = { UserId: 1209 }
    console.log(params,"params")
  }
```

**i want Console params to be like this:**, based on check and uncheck values as 0 and 1.

```
 {
                "Id": "1",
                "HasHomeDashboard": "1",
                "HasUserManagement": "1",
                "HasDicom": "1",
                "HasEMR": "1",
                "HasCaseManagement": "1",
                "HasSystemSettings": "0",
                "HasReport": "1",
                "UserId":"1209"
    }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbyek9?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Try binding `ngModel` to your checkbox

Comment: It seems like, its related with your click fonction. Not checkbox issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified some code,

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objectToArray(menu)">
          <input
            type="checkbox" 
             [checked]="item.value" 
            (click)="selectedMenu($event.target.checked, item)"
            [disabled]="item.IsDisabled">
          <span class="nav-text p-l10">{{item.key}}</span>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
objectToArray(object) {
    const keyValues = [];
    for(let key in object) {
      if(key !== 'Id') {
        const objectToPush = {
          key,
          value: (key == 'HasCaseManagement') ? 1 : object[key],
          IsDisabled: (key == 'HasCaseManagement')
        };
        keyValues.push(objectToPush);
      }
    }
    this.selectedMenuIds = keyValues;
    return keyValues;
  }

  selectedMenu(evt, item) {
    this.userMenu[0][item.key] = this.swapChecked(item.value);
    this.selectedMenuIds[0] = item.value;
  }

  saveSidebar() {
    let params = { Id: 1209, HasCaseManagement:"" }
    this.selectedMenuIds.push(params);
    console.log(this.selectedMenuIds)
  }

  swapChecked(value: any) {
    return (value === 0) ? 1 : 0
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this in the ts you can do like this (it works).

```
  selectedMenu(evt, item) {
    let keyTemp: string = item.key.toString();
    let valueTemp = item.value;
    this.userMenu[0][keyTemp] = this.boxChecked(item.value);
  }

  boxChecked(value: any) {
    if (value === 0) 
      return 1;
    else
      return 0;
  }
```

Hope it can help,
bye

Comment: Can u pls help me to get 1st condition, and that checkbox is working fine, thank you